# Trouble comparing datetime objects

Tags: python, datetime

I have a Python application where I am logging the successes and fails of a try block in a database.  I use `dateime.timedelta` initially in my script to calculate datetime.datetime.now minus 5 minutes. I later use datetime.datetime.strptime(last_time, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p") to convert a unicode timestamp to date.  Lastly, I would like to compare my last_run and now_minus_5 variables.  My script is below;

I do not receive an output for my conditional statement where it should be true.

```
Start = datetime.datetime.now()
    i = 5
    i2= 10
    now_minus_5 = Start - datetime.timedelta(minutes =i)
    now_minus_10 = Start - datetime.timedelta(minutes =i2)

order_fld =  "Time"
        return_flds = ["Time", "SUCCESS"]
        where_str = """Time >=  DATEADD(minute, -5,  GETDATE()) AND SUCCESS = 'NO'"""
        sql_clause = (None,'ORDER BY {} DESC'.format(order_fld))
        last_row = ''
        with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(aTable, return_flds, where_clause=where_str, sql_clause=sql_clause) as cursor:
            last_row = cursor.next()
            last_time = last_row[0]
            last_run = datetime.datetime.strptime(last_time,"%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p")
            last_success = last_row[1]

            print last_run
            print last_success

            if last_run >= now_minus_5:
                print "true"`
```

Comment: What is the value of `last_row`? Please post a reproducible example

Comment: Also, your indentation is all messed up. It would be helpful to correct it.

Comment: And are you sure that `last_run` really is `>= now_minus_5`? I suggest putting an else statement after your conditional and try outputting the arguments to your test. Or better yet, set a `pdb` breakpoint.

Comment: I don't know how it can be more reproducible than this.... the value of last row is `(u'4/24/2015 4:34:10 PM', u'NO')`

Comment: @hgs: Your example is not reproducible because we're missing inputs -- in your case, data from a database. As a result, we can't just run it ourselves to try to figure out what's going on.

Comment: print last_run and now_minus_5.  They are both datetime objects.  My guess is that this could be a millisecond issue.

Comment: You might also want to make sure you're paying attention to time zones when dealing with datetime objects and timestamps in general. It's easy to be off by a few hours when the data sources' time zones disagree.

Comment: @alexander last_run is `2015-04-24 04:34:10` and now_minus_5 is `2015-04-24 16:34:41`

Comment: I see what's going on here, how do I handle this; it appears as if one is on a 24 hr timestamp while the other is 12.

Answer (score 2):

The issue you're seeing is because of incorrect inputs to `strptime()`.

Referencing the [Python docs on strftime and strptime behavior](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior), the notes column for `%p` refers to notes 1 and 2. Specific to your situation is note 2, "When used with the `strptime()` method, the `%p` directive only affects the output hour field if the `%I` directive is used to parse the hour."

Updating your strptime call fixes the invalid behavior:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> last_time = u'4/24/2015 4:34:10 PM'
>>> last_run = datetime.datetime.strptime(last_time,"%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p")
>>> last_run
datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 24, 4, 34, 10)
>>> last_run = datetime.datetime.strptime(last_time,"%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")
>>> last_run
datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 24, 16, 34, 10)
```